Suppose $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ are symmetric, $A-B$ is semi-positive-definite, and $A$ has the same eigenvalues as $B,$ can we derive that $A=B$?
Let $A,B$ be two real symmetric matrices, denote their eigenvalues as $\lambda_1\geq\cdots\geq\lambda_n$ and $\mu_1\geq\cdots\geq\mu_n$ respectively. Suppose $A-B$ is semi-positivedefinite and $\lambda_i=\mu_i$ for each $i,$ can we obtain that $A=B$?
I tried some simple examples, such as $A=\mathrm{diag}(-1,1),$ in this case it follows direct computation that $A=B,$ but I have no idea for the general case, can someone help me? Any help is appreciated!

Semi-positive-definite is not a thing. Symmetric matrix can be definite, semidefinite or indefinite, and further they can be so positively or negatively.

If two matrices, symmetric or otherwise, have the same sequence of eigenvalues (in the algebraic closure), then they have the same trace, and therefore $\operatorname{tr}(A-B)=0$. The only symmetric semidefinite matrix with zero trace is $0$.

Oh! I get it! Thank you so much!
